# Conversion from integer to time in ax 2012

Tags: type-conversion, dynamics-ax-2012

I have requirement where i find the type of field and then i show the value of that field,
 I am using SysDictField.baseType() method to get the type of the field and table.(field) will give me the value but if the field type is Time and when i try to fetch the type using baseType() method it gives me as an Integer so it gives me value like 72000, 62000 etc.. instead of 6.00 PM, 7.00 AM etc..
I want to convert the integer value to Time type so i can display 6.00 PM, 7 AM. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AX [`TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa674480.aspx) type is number of seconds from midnight.

You can use [`time2Str`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa596607.aspx) function or use `div` and `mod` operand to calculate hours and minutes.

Example:

```csharp
info(time2Str(31501, TimeSeparator::Colon, TimeFormat::AMPM));
```